# How to catch an exception thrown by JIRA SOAP in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, exception, soap, jira

I want to catch the exceptions thrown by the login() function in JIRA's SOAP API. The function login throws 2 exceptions. **RemoteAuthenticationException** if the user provided an invalid username or password and **RemoteException** if there was some problem preventing the operation from working.

Currently I'm using this code to catch the exception

```
Try
    ...
Catch jiraException As Exception
    MsgBox(jiraException.toString)
End Try
```

I entered an invalid username and password and printed the exception. It says something like this:
**System.ServiceMode.FaultException: com.atlassian.jira.rpc.exception.RemoteAuthenticationException: Invalid username or password.**

I want to catch the two exceptions separately. How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to catch these as `FaultException Of com.atlassian.jira.rpc.exception.RemoteAuthenticationException` and `FaultException Of com.atlassian.jira.rpc.exception.RemoteException`.

Comment: Can you please tell which dll or reference or class is required for this exception?

Comment: Just access their SOAP API via "Add Service Reference"